# App Center: In-app updates disabled: This release was either side-loaded or downloaded using a browser in private mode

Tags: xcode, fastlane, visual-studio-app-center, fastlane-gym

When using `fastlane` to generate an `Enterprise` ipa with the following `fastlane` code

```
platform :ios do
  desc "Create ipa for Enterprise distribution"
  lane :generate_ipa do
    gym scheme: 'SchemeName',
        configuration: 'Release',
        export_method: 'enterprise',
        clean: true,
        output_directory: "./fastlane/builds"
  end
end
```

It will work and an ipa will be generated. However the very first time I open the app, I get the warning
 `In-app updates disabled: This release was either side-loaded or downloaded using a browser in private mode.`

Any help is greatly appreciated!